# DllMain not being called

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll

I have a DllMain defined as so:

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                   DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                   LPVOID lpReserved
                 )
{ 

int i=0, DoHijack=0;

switch (ul_reason_for_call)
{
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    hMod = hModule;
    hProcessCenter = ::FindWindow(NULL, _T("Form1"));

    ExtractPaths(hModule, ExePath, &kNTIExeName, kNTIDllPath, &kNTIDllName);

    //Only hook target processses
    for(i=0; i < NB_TARGETS; i++)
    {
        if(strstr(kNTIExeName, Targets[i]))
            DoHijack=1;
    }

    if(DoHijack)
    {
            DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)Real_DrawText, Mine_DrawText); // <- magic
        DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)Real_ExtTextOut, Mine_ExtTextOut); 
        DetourTransactionCommit();
    break;   
    }      

case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        break;
case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        DetourTransactionBegin(); 
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)Real_DrawText, Mine_DrawText);
        DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)Real_ExtTextOut, Mine_ExtTextOut); // <- magic
        DetourTransactionCommit();
    break;
}
return TRUE;
 }
```

This is a project that I have bought home from work and after I compile and run it the dllmain is never being called, hence my problem which is the process_attach switch is never hit.  What could be causing this to occur?  Something in the compiler, one of the linking options?

The dll functions perfectly at work...

Thanks.

Comment: What do you do inside `DllMain`? Can you post some code please?

Comment: How are you "running" the DLL?

Comment: What kind of company do you work for that ships products that hides DLLs?  This is malicious, voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "run" a DLL. Perhaps you've built it as an executable project, for which `DllMain` has no special significance.

Comment: Sorry, just poor choice of words, its compiled as a dll.  As I said, it all works fine when I compile it on my work computer but not at home, I think one of the compile setting is different and I am wondering if anybody knows which one...

Answer (score 0):

Looked at it with fresh eyes this morning and realized that dllmain was being called but in fact I had made a mistake in one of the check NBTargets values which is why my code was not firing...

back to it...