# Dllmain not being called?

Tags: c++

I was writing a dllmain like this:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "init.h"
#include <iostream>
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
//std::cout<<"hi\n"; //only for debug. did not shown.
switch (fdwReason)
{
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        // attach to process
        // return FALSE to fail DLL load
        //std::cout<<"hello\n"; //only for debug. did not shown.
        init(); //did not run :(
        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        // detach from process
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        // attach to thread
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        // detach from thread
        break;
}
return TRUE; // succesful
}
```

but after a test program uses LoadLibrary(), nothing happened,
no hello or hi on the screen.
Would you like to figure out the problem? Many Thanks!

P.S. I have watched the question [DllMain not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007161/dllmain-not-being-called)
but it still not help.

PS2: the caller program is like

```
int main()
{
cout<<"This is a test program to test.\n";
HINSTANCE hinstDLL;
hinstDLL=LoadLibrary("ijl15.dll");
cout<<"Look like everything goes well.\n";
cout<<hinstDLL;
return 0;
}
```

The tester program outputs:

```
This is a test program to test.
Look like everything goes well.
0x6a980000
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.007 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: Hmm... seems okay... can you add the LoadLibrary() code?
Also, just to be certain - you are looking for printouts in the console window, right?

Comment: I was willing to see init() being runned; but it never works so I tried some cout but it still not work.

Comment: What are your linker switches for the all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some tries(alot :( ) I found that I missed

```
#define DLL_EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
```

This makes the function name correctly and finally the DLLMain is successfully called. Anyway thanks you all!

Comment: How does it solve the problem? Where do you then use `DLL_EXPORT` in the code?

Comment: Not a proper solution to address this problem. Because the place of application for this solution wasn't provided, either a code sample or something to help others learn and be able to use it.

Comment: Please explain where did you put that DLL_EXPORT define?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that it's your console interaction code that is off. You could try doing something a little less subtle, like opening a window or `ShellExecute()`ing a sound.

Comment: OutputDebugString() is great for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Ferruccio in init() there are other things like writing log to file, but it didn't work at all... At last DLLMAIN was failed :( but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You are severely limited in what you can do in DLLMain. specifically, doing any I/O is normally a no-no. It's there to do some simple initialisation, not to act like main() does in an executable.

Comment: Actually, the hello and hi are only for debug, and init() didn't run.

Comment: @xxbidiao OK, what does init() do?

Comment: About the IO: are you sure? AFAIK in `DllMain` the only thing you can rely on is that kernel32.dll is loaded, and the Win32 IO functions are there. Obviously you can't be sure about what the CRT does, but with direct win32 IO you should be safe. Anyway, agreed that DllMain is just for small "internal" initialization, for heavy stuff you should provide a separate function.

Comment: @Butterworth open some log files, call a hookdll function,maybe it is like the main(). The whole program should hook an dll,exporting its functions and open a thread for doing other things.

Comment: @Matteo As far as I'm aware stdout & stdin won't be available.

Comment: @xxbidiao I'd comment out the logging stuff. And starting a thread sounds dicey.

Comment: File IO in generall seems okay as the official docs explicitly state that "Open, read from, and write to files" is safe. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices

Answer (score 0):

Is `LoadLibrary` actually returning a value (what is displayed by your `cout<<hinstDLL` call) ?

Is your dll in the same directory or available via the `PATH` environment variable?

Do you have multiple versions of your dll in different places (release vs debug)?

Comment: The test program results in:This is a test program to test.
Look like everything goes well.
0x6a980000
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.007 s
Press any key to continue.
...Something like that